# IMX477 module not giving normal frames with jetson nano

Tags: camera, embedded, gstreamer, nano, nvidia-jetson-nano

I just received my IMX477, which I ordered for good resolution. I am able to get feed through gstreamer from the pipeline, but I don’t know what it is showing. Also, the camera is working and I want to use it as a normal camera.
[terminal output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vfIqP.jpg)
[Camera Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4uWFe.jpg)

**Pixel format is RG10**

```
v4l2-ctl --list-formats-ext
ioctl: VIDIOC_ENUM_FMT
    Index       : 0
    Type        : Video Capture
    Pixel Format: 'RG10'
    Name        : 10-bit Bayer RGRG/GBGB
        Size: Discrete 4032x3040
            Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
        Size: Discrete 3840x2160
            Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
        Size: Discrete 1920x1080
            Interval: Discrete 0.017s (60.000 fps)
```

**videoconvert does not support RG10**
**dmesg kernel logs**

```
dmesg | grep imx477
[    1.335158] imx477 7-001a: tegracam sensor driver:imx477_v2.0.6
[    1.635508] imx477 7-001a: imx477_board_setup: error during i2c read probe (-121)
[    1.643134] imx477 7-001a: board setup failed
[    1.647608] imx477: probe of 7-001a failed with error -121
[    1.647995] imx477 8-001a: tegracam sensor driver:imx477_v2.0.6
[    2.224479] vi 54080000.vi: subdev imx477 8-001a bound
```

What should I do? I just want to use it as a normal camera. No special purpose!! How can I use it as an ordinary camera?